# DB drivers not specified

Tags: sql, oracle, perl

I have perl script which on running gives me this error.What could be the error ? because i just changed the host and DB connection setings. Earlier the script worked fine.

I get below error

```
"dbi:Oracle:host=localhost;sid=nms", 'user', 'password', no database driver specified and DBI_DSN env var not set at ./test.pl line 9..
```

And here's the code:

```
sub connect{
 my $self = shift; 
 $logger->debug("Connecting to: " . $self->{config}->{connection}->{host});
 $self->{db} = DBI->connect("$self->{config}->{connection}->{host}", 
                            "$self->{config}->{login}->{user}", 
                            "$self->{config}->{login}->{password}") 
                    or ($logger->fatal("Connection Failed : " . $DBI::errstr . " : " . $self->{config}->{login}->{user} . ":" . $self->{config}->{login}->{password} ) 
                    and return 0); 
  return 1; }–
```

Comment: The function am using here is                                      sub connect{
    my $self = shift;
    $logger->debug("Connecting to: " . $self->{config}->{connection}->{host});
    $self->{db} = DBI->connect("$self->{config}->{connection}->{host}", "$self->{config}->{login}->{user}", "$self->{config}->{login}->{password}") or
                                                                                            ($logger->fatal("Connection Failed : " . $DBI::errstr . " : " . $self->{config}->{login}->{user} . ":" . $self->{config}->{login}->{password} ) and return 0);
    return 1;
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing `"dbi:Oracle:"`, and when connecting to Oracle you don't use host but refer to name from [`Tnsnames.ora`](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Tnsnames.ora#Text_editor), ie. `ORA11` or using complete string instead:

```
$CFG->{TNS_NAME} = "(DESCRIPTION = 
   (ADDRESS_LIST =
     (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 127.0.0.1)(PORT = 1521))
   )
 (CONNECT_DATA =
   (SERVICE_NAME = ORA11)
 )
)";
```

---

```
# ..
$CFG->{TNS_NAME} = "ORA11";

my $DB = DBI->connect(
  "dbi:Oracle:",
  "$CFG->{USER}/$CFG->{PASSWORD}@". $CFG->{TNS_NAME},
  "",
  {
    ChopBlanks => 1,
    AutoCommit => 0,
    RaiseError => 1,
  },
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your `dns` var is correct ? 
it should be formatted like that : `"dbi:<driver>:<database>:<host>:<port>";`

```
use DBI;

$database = 'your_db_name';
$host = 'test.com';
$port = '1521';
$user = 'your_user';
$password = 'your_password';

$dsn = 'dbi:Oracle:'.$database.':'.$host.':'.$port;
$db = DBI->connect($dsn, $user, $password, { 'RaiseError' => 1, 'PrintError' => 0, 'AutoCommit' => 0 })
    or die "Unable to connect: $DBI::errstr";
```

You can also try to set your `ORACLE_HOME` and `ORACLE_OWNER` env variable before your `DBI->connect()`:

```
$ENV{'ORACLE_HOME'} = '...' # path to your oracle lib
$ENV{'ORACLE_OWNER'} = 'oracle'; # Owner
```